# colorbox div won't display

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I am trying to show a hidden div in a colorbox on click

I cant figure out how to show the div inside the colorbox

the  div is hidden, but I want it to be visible when it is displayed inside the colorbox obviously

```
<div class="test">test</div> // on click

<div id="messageform" style="display: none;"> // show this in colorbox
TEST
</div>    



$('.test').click(function(){
$.colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", open:true, href:"#messageform" }); 
});
```

this works only when the form messageform is not hidden, but how can i show on click in the colorbox?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either wrap the `messageform` inside a div that has `display:none` or you can set it to show on click:

```
$('.test').click(function(){
  $('#messageform').show();
  $.colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", open:true, href:"#messageform" }); 
});
```

Here is a demo with a container that is set to display none:http://jsfiddle.net/fbenariac/4vuDC/

Also you could use the colorbox events to show/hide: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/LK4tt/1/

```
$('.test').click(function(){

$.colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", open:true, href:"#messageform",
            onClosed: function() {
                 $('#messageform').hide();
            },
            onOpen: function() {
                 $('#messageform').show();
            }
           }); 
});​
```

Comment: thank you so much.. quick question
I plan to submit this form via ajax from the colorbox, how do I close the colorbox after success

Comment: Sure in the `success` event of the ajax you can close it: `$.fn.colorbox.close();`

Comment: I recommend use `onCleanup` instead `onClosed`. In some cases (if you put `messageForm` inside a `div` with `display: none`) the content of colorbox will splash in page by little seconds and hide. Using cleanup, we make sure it will be hidden before colorbox closes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make overlay for your base div, which you want to see in popup.
2. Add style to overlay display:none
3. Then call your js. JS will popup content in popupoverlay...

HTML

```
    <a id="openpopup" href="popup" class="button">Details</a>

    <div class="popupoverlay" style="display:none">
        <div id="popup">
         some content...
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    $("#openpopup").colorbox({
        inline:true, 
        href: "#popup",
        width:666,
    });
```

Comment: This is the better answer.